# Retrieving Field from Parent Table with JPA ManytoOne

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-one

I hypothetically have two tables t_document and t_employee.  The table t_document has two fields, id and owner_id, with owner_id having a foreign key relationship to t_employee.  The table t_employee has two fields, id and name.  My dilemma is, how do I set up a JPA entity (using version 1.x) such that the following NamedNativeQuery fetches a document along with the owner's name and properly populates the entity?

```
SELECT d.id, e.name
FROM t_document d
JOIN t_employee e ON d.owner_id = e.id;
```

For starters, I've included the basic beginnings of my Document class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_DOCUMENT")
public class Document
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending upon the relationship(I am assuming OneToMany as one Employee can have Many Document) you can design your class as follow:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="T_EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="ID")
    private long id;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="employee")
    Collection<EmployeeDocument> documents = new ArrayList<>();
}


@Entity
@Table(name="T_DOCUMENT")
public class EmployeeDocument {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="ID")
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="OWNER_ID")
    private Employee employee;
}
```

This should server your purpose.